# Unable to display two forms in a view - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I have two related models (Sim and Payment - A Sim can have many Payment). On searching of Sim (by ID ) i want its detail to be populated in a form (*which i am able to*). But using the same form i want to save the details of Payment model as well and at the same time want to update the Sim model as well.

I am able to populate only Sim form using the id but the AddPaymentForm is not populating.

```
def updatePayment(request, id):
    sim  = get_object_or_404(Sim, pk=id)
    payment = AddPaymentForm()
    sim_form = UpdatePayment(request.POST, instance=sim)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # sim_form = UpdatePayment(request.POST, instance=payment)
        payment_form = AddPaymentForm()
        try:
            if payment_form.is_valid():
                payment_form.save()
                sim_form.save()
                messages.success(request, ("Payment has been updated"))
            else:
                messages.warning(request, ("Data in fields is incorrect, please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, ("Error: {}".format(e)))
    else:
        form = UpdatePayment(instance=sim)
        payment = AddPaymentForm()
    context = {'payment': payment, 'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'payment/updatePayment.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code in line number 7, payment_form = AddPaymentForm() is an empty form and has not received any data. It should be

```
payment_form = AddPaymentForm(request.POST)
```

to make sure that the instance receives information from the POST action.

```
        payment_form  = AddPaymentForm(request.POST)
        payment_form = payment_form.save(commit=False) ----> (1)
        try:
            if payment_form.is_valid():
                // Add some logic that links your payment form with SIM form, 
                //for example, like, payment_form(sim=sim_form.id) -------> (2)
                payment_form.save()            
                sim_form.save()
                messages.success(request, ("Payment has been updated"))
            else:
                messages.warning(request, ("Data in fields is incorrect, please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, ("Error: {}".format(e)))
```

1. You need to false save your form instance before you can do .is_valid() on your form.
2. False saving your form allows you to manipulate some part of your form, that will allow you to link your payment_form with the new sim.